# How can EC2 instance access internet IP starting with the same CIDR prefix of the VPC the EC2 instance is in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routes, amazon-vpc, cidr

How can EC2 instance access internet IP starting with the same CIDR prefix of the VPC the EC2 instance is in?

Assume you have a VPC with CIDR 123.78.0.0/16
and you have the following entry in the routing table to allow VPC EC2 instances to access each other

- destination  :123.78.0.0/16
- target       :local
  How can you access an internet server with IP 123.78.x.x (for example 123.78.1.1) from an EC2 instance in this VPC?

Comment: Do you own this public IP range and have delegated it to AWS?

Comment: Is this an actual business problem you are trying to solve, or is it a question from a test/assignment you have been given? If it is 'real', then why do you have a VPC with a CIDR in the 'public' range of IP addresses rather than a [private range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)?

Comment: @john   I can't get your point. What do you mean by VPC with CIDR in the public range?

Comment: @maurice, I don't own any public addresses, I am just wondering if there was an internet server with IP address 123.78.1.1, how would an EC2 machine in the VPC access this IP?

Comment: `123.78.x.x` is a "public" IP address, meaning that it belongs to somebody. In private networks (eg your corporate network, or a VPC), you will typically want to use a [private IP address range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). The most common ones start with `10.x.x.x`. Do you have a particular reason for wanting to use `123.78.x.x`?

Comment: This is not really the format for a networking deep dive, I suggest you research how IP-routing works and how technologies like Public IPv4 and Private IPv4 addresses as well as Network Address Translation (NAT) interact to make the internet as we know it possible.

Comment: Thanks @John, your last comment answers my question. I wasn't aware that there are conventions for how to allocate IP ranges in VPC to avoid collision with public IPs

Answer (score 0):

You will typically want to use a [private IP address range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) with your VPC to avoid clashing with somebody who owns and operates a public IP address.

Private ranges are:

- `10.0.0.0/8`
- `172.16.0.0/12`
- `192.168.0.0/16`

You can also use subsets of these ranges, such as `10.0.0.0/16`.

The additional benefit of using a private IP range is that Internet traffic cannot route to these IP addresses without going via a NAT Router (such as the one you have at home, which translates a public IP address to a private IP address on your home network).

While it *is* possible to use Public IP addresses (eg `123.78.0.0/16`) in a VPC, this should be avoided unless you actually own the range and want to allow routing to it.